# Titanium SDK 3.2 [ERROR] : Invalid "--ios-version" value "7.0" 7.0.3

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

When I upgraded to titanium SDK version 3.2, I had an error when running on iOS says: titanium Invalid "--ios-version" value "7.0" Accepted values: 7.0.3, is there any possible way to solve this ?

Comment: I get the same error. Tiapp.xml is set `<sdk-version>3.2.0.GA</sdk-version>`, `alloy -version 1.3.0`, Studio version `3.2.0.201312191547`. I get this error regardless, but ONLY if I try to build for distro. And, yes, I have my Apple distro certs in my keychain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue.
I were able to solve it by changing the tiapp.xml node
changed

```
<sdk-version>3.1.3.GA</sdk-version>
```

to

```
<sdk-version>3.2.0.GA</sdk-version>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can also set 3.2.0.GA in TiApp Editor (http://i.imgur.com/n1rZDCG.png), just noticed if you want to use iOS 6 you must set 3.1.3.GA.

Answer (score 1):

minimum iOS version to work with Ti sdk 3.2.0 is 7 so you need to set iOS version to 7.

you can do that by right clicking on your project root folder then choose Run As-> Run Configuration option where you can set ios sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a fix. I have changed my project's sdk version to 3.2.0.GA (updated) then build my application via cli and execute the following command on the project directory:

```
titanium build --platform ios --ios-version 7.0.3
```

App build successfully (no errors encountered) and it opens the iOS simulator v7.0.3.

---

Update: Issue no longer encountered after updating [titanium-studio](/questions/tagged/titanium-studio) to 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

Work fine with ti SDK 3.2.0

- Ti SDK : 3.1.3.GA
- Ti: 3.2.0
- Alloy: 1.4.0 or 1.3.0
- OS: mac os x 10.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
Problem seems to be solved when building with the 3.2.0 SDK, however then other issues emerge.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by just loading the xcode project from the 'build' folder and seeing the actual error that xcode was throwing. it told me that I had a 'module' that no longer supported 'NavigationGroup' class. I also installed the latest xcode updates and the latest Ti.Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your sdk version in order to make it work with 7.0.3.
From the console:

```
ti sdk select 3.2.0.GA
```

You can find more info in the [CLI documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-SDKSelect)

Also make sure you update your tiapp.xml file as @Anand suggested

Answer (score 0):

An update for Titanium SDK 3.1.3 has been released, the thing is 3.1.3 only supported up to iOS simulator 7.0, but now Appcelerator added support for 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Open ti.xml file
Under Build Properties, find the Titanium SDK field.
Select 3.2.0.GA

If it is not an option, go to menu option 
Help > Check for Titanium Updates