# Titanium performs full rebuild after Titanium Studio 3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

After I upgraded Titanium Studio to 3.2, whenever I build a project with SDK v. 3.2.0.GA the underlying XCode project is built from the start. This is a real pain as I have added external libraries on the XCode project and they get lost each time.

On previous versions, Studio was not doing a full rebuild so it was not even necessary to compile the project.All that was needed was to do changes, go to the emulator close the app and then reopen it.

Trying to install a pre-3.2 sdk version causes the following error [Titanium SDK 3.2 [ERROR] : Invalid "--ios-version" value "7.0" 7.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684235/titanium-sdk-3-2-error-invalid-ios-version-value-7-0-7-0-3)

Could it be a flag or something else on the Studio preferences that I am missing?

Comment: Same issue. Tried updating everything (CLI, SDK & Studio) to bleeding edge versions (3.3.0.v2014etc...) and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project first (or just remove the "build" folder) and have the latest `titanium` cli (`npm install -g titanium`).

In case you have a custom `Info.plist` in your project try to build the proyect without it. If it works, then is something with it.